jupyter lab: opening a ipynb file from another ipynb file using %run, same directory already
In jupyter notebook, I am trying to open a ipynb file create.ipynb in which I made a class called Animals, from another ipynb file Coursera_test.ipynb. I have already checked, they are in the same directory. They are literally just in my desktop.
create.ipynb contains the following code
class Animals:
    def __init__(self, animal, age, colour):
        self.animaled= animal
        self.ageed= age
        self.coloured= colour
        self.cuteness= "the cutest"
    
    def move(self):
        print(f"The {self.animaled} is moving")

    def stop (self):
        print (f"The {self.animaled} has stopped")

Coursera_test.ipynb contains the following code
%run "create.ipynb"
from create import Animals

When I run the lines one by one in the Coursera_test.ipynb,the first line with the run command has no error, but the second throws out the following error message
----> 1 from create import Animals

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create'

I also tried
%run /Users/myname/Desktop/create.ipynb
from create import Animals

and got the same error message. I already checked for typos etc.  The strange thing is that when I export the create.ipynb file into a python file create.py, and run the correct code for opening such python files, the code runs fine with no error message i.e. I can indeed import Animals from create.
Can anyone help me with this? I already checked the other answers on stack overflow but no one else seems to have exactly the same problem.

Your username is apt here. (I kid.) Really what is going on is that you are trying to do things two ways. Pick one and use it. For what you are doing with %run noteboo.ipynb it should be enough because by default with notebooks, it runs the notebook you pointed at with %run in the current namespace. (This is not the default with using %run with a .py script by the way. You need to add the -i flag there to say you want to run it 'interactive' in the same namespace as the current notebook.)  So what about from create import Animals. That would work as another way to go if ...

 the create file was a .py script. You cannot import directly from a .ipynb Jupyter file. You are using Python in the kernel and it wants Python by default, just as if you were running Python the traditional ways, i.e., in the interpreter/console or triggering a script from the command line. (I cannot recall if you can use import with a .ipy script; I know you can use run with .ipy.) However, there are ways to do it if you bring in some other tools and use Python to signal that is what you are doing. See ...

 'How can I import from another ipython-notebook?', here, here, here, and here.

Back to your title: To make things clear, with %run "create.ipynb", you are not just opening the notebook file. You are also running the code in the notebook file you invoke with %run the current namespace of the running notebook, and so I'm not sure why you are then adding the import. The import though of the notebook might be what you'd prefer; however, you have to go through extra hoops to make that work. It really depends on what other code is in things and how polluted you want to or don't want your namespace. (And remember, %run with a .py file works a little different.)

It seems the main goal you are trying to accomplish is to actually import the class (Animals) contained within the create.ipynb notebook, and not necessarily the notebook itself.
Proposed Solution
EDIT: Following @Wayne's comment(s): The Animals class can be used directly once %run create.ipynb is executed first. The availability can be queried using dir().

The initial solution was to have %run create.ipynb import Animals as the first line but the appended import statement is redundant (although, that was the technique suggested here).
The import statement in Coursera_test.ipynb should look like this:
# Works, but is redundant
# %run create.ipynb import Animals

%run create.ipynb

# Animals class is immediately available for use
dog = Animals("Dalmatian", "3", "Black and White")

# Fancy tabulation
properties = vars(dog)
pads = [len(str(max(properties.keys()))), len(str(max(properties.values())))]
row0 = "| %-9s ||" % "Property"
row1 = "| %-9s ||" % "Value"
for k,v in zip(properties.keys(), properties.values()):
    pad = max(max(pads), len(k), len(v))
    top = " %-*s |" % (pad, k)
    bottom = " %-*s |" % (pad, v)
    row0 += top
    row1 += bottom
print(row0); print("-"*len(row0));print(row1)

Output:


If create.ipynb just includes the first code block in the OP, I'm not seeing %run "create.ipynb" import Animals be needed. %run create.ipynb results in the same thing when you run dir() in the next cell to chek the namespace,  whether you include import Animals or not.

@Wayne: If you use just %run create.ipynb, you won't be able to access the Animals class (which is OP's main objective) - that's the difference. You have to immediately specify what to be obtained or imported from the notebook you're running via the magic command as the content is being read, thus, %run create.ipynb import Animals.

No, you do not. I just saved the first block in the OP's post in a Jupyter .ipynb file as create.ipynb. Then I opened a new notebooks and ran in the first cell, %run create.ipynb. Then in the next cell I ran dog = Animals("Dalmatian", "3", "Black and White") and that ran without error. type(dog) in the third cell gave me type of __main__.Animals. I get the same thing if I run it with or without import Animals after the run command because everything after %run create.ipynb gets treated as an argument to the call to notebook and the notebook doesn't do anything with arguments.

 I explained earlier how you could check and see the class was available using dir(). This expanded example in my last comment just further emphasizes all you need is %run create.ipynb part of the line magic. The Animals class is available to create an instance of it because after running %run create.ipynb in the notebook session, the class remains available for use because it has been read into the namespace of the active Jupyter .ipynb (or IPython) session.

Had to re-read your comment. You were indeed correct, running %run create.ipynb in the first cell, and then directly creating an Animals object in a subsequent cell works just fine. I will update my answer to reflect this.
